# one simplemodal script to handle images

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have http://communitychessclub.com with about 20-30 smaller jpegs scattered throughout the website. I want to click on the image and have simplemodal popup the larger photo. Problem is I don't want to use separate scripts for each thumbnail. I just want to pass the height and width of each jpeg to a single simplemodal script. This seems like it would be faster bc the computer would know what to do w/o searching for a script for each image related to it. 
Maybe I could pass a css height and width with an "onclick= ... etc.

http://chesstao.com/test-2.php is the sample page.

Is this possible? What should I do?

```
<a href="images/aveskulov-medium.jpg" class="photo" />pic-1</a>
<a href="images/Jeff%20Plew.jpg" class="photo" />pic-2</a>

<!-- new code which works, but modal isn't centered V or H-->

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".photo").click(function(e) {
      var hrefval= $(this).attr("href"); 
      $.modal('<img src=" ' + hrefval + '">', { 
        containerCss: {autoPosition:'true'}, 
        overlayClose: true 
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is each image a different size and will the modal versions be larger than the clicked on versions?

Comment: Yes. The images vary in size and the modals will be larger than the clicked-on thumbnail images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually looks good, there are just some simple typos you need to correct to make it work properly:

1. You never close your call to `$.modal` with a final `)`.
2. You don't actually close your `$(document).ready` function.

Here's a fixed version:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".photo").click(function(e) {
      var hrefval= $(this).attr("href"); 
      $.modal('<img src=" ' + hrefval + '">', { 
        containerCss: { height:'auto',width:'auto'}, 
        overlayClose: true 
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

And [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9cc8/1/)

I'd recommend being diligent about proper whitespace nesting so you can spot issues like this with a glance.

Additionally, using a javascript console when you're doing development like this can allow you to see error messages from typos, that way you'll know if your concept is flawed, or if there's a missing character preventing your code from being run.

Comment: The left edge is at the center which is wrong. I might need to add:  modal.setPosition(); but I am not sure where it goes.

Comment: I think the issue there is actually that the image hasn't been loaded before you display it, so `simpleModal` aligns itself for a `0x0` size image.  The reason I'm guessing that is because if you open them once they look wrong, but the second time I click the links the modal view looks correct.  I see that you're passing the height and width into the `containerCss` option, you might try passing the same values to `minHeight` and `minWidth` in the options as well, so `containerCss: { // etc }, minHeight: 123, minWdith: 123`