# simplemodal direct <div> w/o iframe

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have a previous post regarding simplemodal and an iframe [How to invoke simplemodal with onclick inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031205/how-to-invoke-simplemodal-with-onclick-inline)

**But now I want to invoke a div not an iframe file.**

What I have works very nice with simplemodal invoking an iframe:

```
 <a href="http://ibm.com" data-width="586" data-height="570" class="ibm_modal">IBM</a>

<script>
    $('.ibm_modal').click(function(e) {
        var hrefval= $(this).attr("href"); 
        var $this = $(this); var height_len = $this.data("height"); 
        var width_len = $this.data("width"); 
        $.modal(
            '<iframe src="' + hrefval + '" height="' +height_len + '" width="' +width_len + '" style="border:none; overflow:auto; margin:0 9px; padding:0; padding-top:10px">', {
           closeHTML:"", 
           overlayCss: {
               backgroundColor:"#000", 
               opacity:85
           },
           containerCss: {
               backgroundColor:"#B9B54F", 
               borderColor:"#B9B54F", 
               border:0, 
               padding:15, 
               height:'height_len+15', 
               width:'width_len+15'
           }, 
           overlayClose: true
        }); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Instead I want simplemodal to call a div. Conceptually I don't grok this.

**I think I understand that this following line has to scrapped and possibly replaced with a div reference, is that right?:** 
    ''

Is this OK? I don't think it specifies the target div. So it dw.

```
<a data-width="586" data-height="570" class="ibm_modal">IBM</a>

<div style="display:hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

I want a link that when clicked opens the sample div above. How can I do that? I don't understand the basic example in Eric's webpage. I like the syntax I have and **I just want to change it to invoke a div instead of an iframe and file.**

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<div>` an `id` or `class` then use that for your jquery selector.

Example:

```
<div id='myContainer'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p></div>


$(".modal").click(function(e) {

    $('#myContainer").modal({

      width: $this.data("width"),
      height: $this.data("height"),
      animate: true,
      opacity: 60
    })
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  })
```

Comment: Not working... I tried this at http://communitychessclub.com/modal-test.php and it displays the target div which is supposed to be hidden. Also, shoudn't this be a class instead of an ID since this modal will be invoked several times within a page? The height and width are passed with: data-width="586" data-height="570".

Comment: I'm having a hard time organizing the concepts.

Comment: @verlanger Why not keep using the same modal (changing the content and hiding/showing)?

Comment: Because an iframe requires an html source but I direct modal can use a div.